# VBA Outlook Insert Image to Appintment

Tags: vba, outlook, jpeg

Once i have opened an appointment in outlook I am then wanting to insert a jpg into the body of the invite by using a vba script, these will be phone details in the form of a jpg.

```
Const MyPath = "C:\diallist\"
Const MyPicture = "TestDialList.jpg"

Dim myItem As Object

Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem()
myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
.Attachments.Add MyPath & MyPicture
.HTMLBody = "<html><p>This is a picture</p>" & "<img src=cid:" & _   Replace(MyPicture, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>"
.Display
End With
```

Any help is gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the ApppointmentItem object does not expose the HTMLBody property, only MailItem does. For the mail item, you need to add the image as an attachment and set its PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property using Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty to the cid used by the img tag in th HTML body. Again, that will bot work for appointments sicne they only support RTF.

To add a picture to an item currently being displayed, use `Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Shapes.AddPicture`.

Comment: That worked like a dream however now when the invite gets to the other end you get a blank border with the error.  The linked image cannot be displayed,  The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.

Comment: Ignore me its because i had    ', True, False  at the end of Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Shapes.AddPicture.